# Choosing a method based on a field value in a Django model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, polymorphism

In outline, I have a Django model and I want instances to have different behaviours according to the value of one of its fields:

```
ANIMAL_TYPES = ('cow', 'african swallow', 'dog')
ANIMAL_TYPE_CHOICES = tuple(enumerate(ANIMALS, start=1))

class Animal(models.Model):
    animal_type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=ANIMAL_TYPE_CHOICES)
    # ... other model fields

    def speak_cow(self):
        return 'moo'

    def speak_african_swallow(self):
        return 'squawk'

    def speak_dog(self):
        return 'woof'

    choose_speak = {i: getattr(Animal,'speak_{}'.format(
             name.replace(' ', '_'))) for (i, name) in ANIMAL_TYPE_CHOICES}

    def speak(self):
        return Animal.speak[self.animal_type](self)
```

The goal is to be able to call `speak()` on an instance of `Animal` and let the class pick the correct `speak` method. (To be clear: the `speak` methods do quite a lot more than just return a string.)

This doesn't work: `Animal` isn't defined by the time I'm using it in my dictionary comprehension for `choose_speak`. At the moment, my work-around is to use

```
choose_speak = [None, speak_cow, speak_african_swallow, speak_dog]
```

but is there a way to automatically generate what I want so I don't have to add any new methods I define (e.g. `speak_sheep`) by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also define a list with all the sounds of animals... i.e.

```
 ANIMAL_SOUNDS = ['moo', 'squawk'..]
```

That way you wouldn't have to define new methods. 
Use it in speak like:

```
def speak(self):
    return ANIMAL_SOUNDS[self.animal_type]
```

**Edit**:

just for the sake of it, I played around a little bit and came up with this code in pure python which may be close to what you want:

```
ANIMAL_TYPES = ('cow', 'african swallow', 'dog')
ANIMAL_TYPE_CHOICES = tuple(enumerate(ANIMAL_TYPES, start=1))

class Animal(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.choose_speak = {i: getattr(self, 'speak_{}'.format(
            name.replace(' ', '_'))) for (i, name) in ANIMAL_TYPE_CHOICES}

    animal_type = 1

    def speak_cow(self):
        return 'moo'

    def speak_african_swallow(self):
        return 'squawk'

    def speak_dog(self):
        return 'woof'

    def speak(self):
        return self.choose_speak[self.animal_type]()

animal = Animal()
animal.speak()
```

Note: overriding model's `__init__` is not Django best practice, as shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects):

Comment: I think I may have over-simplified my example: the `speak` methods do rather more than just output a string!

Comment: @xnx Sorry for the misunderstanding. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is `getattr`:

```
def speak(self):
    method_name = choose_speak[self.animal_type]
    method = getattr(self, method_name)
    return method()
```

But were I you, I would just use `if ... else` in `speak` for now, because it's much more simple and explicit.

Comment: I could do it this way (if `choose_speak` is a list of method names), but my question is about how I can create a list or dictionary of method _objects_ at the time my class is defined.

Comment: I'd rather not use `if...else` because that creates one more thing to maintain: if I add an animal type, I have to add a choice, add a speak method _and_ then add an `elif` clause.

Comment: Well, that's what most text book tells you anyway. But I would start with something as simple as `if ... else` and refactor only when I see some pattern repeating in my code.

Comment: If your requirement is just to encapsulate different sounds of animals, then you should just follow @lgor 's suggestion.

Comment: What's more, it's not clear why you still want the dict when you can just use `getattr`.

Comment: Well, I suppose my reasoning was that it might be slower to use `getattr` than to index a list or look up in a (small) dictionary. I might well be wrong.

Comment: If you really care about the tiny performance difference, then you should just use `if ... else`, which would be the fastest solution here.

Comment: By the way, it's possible to build the `dict` you desire with metaclass or class decorator. But don't do it, it would be an overkill.